# Why am I unable to print my number constant in NASM Assembly?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, assembly, nasm, 32-bit

Learning NASM Assembly in 32-bit Ubuntu. I am somewhat confused:

In `.bss`, I reserve a byte for a variable:

```
num resb 1
```

Later I decided to give it a value of `5`:

```
mov byte [num],5
```

And at some point print it out:

```
mov EAX,4
mov EBX,0
mov ECX,num
add ECX,'0'   ; From decimal to ASCII
mov EDX,1
int 0x80
```

But it isn't printing anything.

I'm guessing that the problem is when I give `num` its value of `5`. I originally wanted to do this:

```
mov byte num,5
```

As I thought that `num` refers to a position in memory, and so `mov` would copy `5` to such position. But I got an error saying

> invalid combination of opcode and operands

So basically, why is the program not printing 5? And also, why was my suggestion above invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print using `int 0x80` and code `4` you need `ECX` to be the address of the byte to print. You added `'0'` to the address of `num` that was in `ECX` before you called the `print` routine, so it was the address of something else out in memory somewhere.

You may want something like this. I created a separate area, `numout` to hold the ASCII version of `num`:

```
numout resb 1
....

mov EAX,4
mov EBX,0
mov CL,[num]
add CL,'0'
mov [numout],CL
mov ECX,numout
mov EDX,1
int 0x80
```